# Get route name from inside view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributerouting

Using [Attribute Routing](http://attributerouting.net/#route-names) you can define a route name. Is there a way I can get the name of the used route from inside my view?

Comment: Here is a similar question about how to get this info in the controller. The answer could be used to also get it in the view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363211/how-can-i-get-the-route-name-in-controller-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1083781/538387), you can use:

```
@{ var x = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"]; }
```

to get route data. Then according to [the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2330191/538387) of this post: "[How to get a custom attribute from object instance in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2329738/538387)", you can pull out the attributes.

Comment: The first part I already knew about, the 2nd part... I'm not sure how that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like a real good idea.  You should probably add the route name to view data or the view model instead.

Comment: Then I would have to do it in every single action. I want to use it in my layout.

Answer (score 1):

`MapMvcAttributeRoutes` has multiple overloads which expects a parameter for `IDirectRouteProvider` implementation. This interface is responsible for generating routes. The default implementation for this interface is `DefaultDirectRouteProvider`. Create a custom class that inherits from `DefaultDirectRouteProvider` and override required methods like `GetActionDirectRoutes` or `GetControllerDirectRoutes`. In this method you will get `RouteEntry` which contains the route name. You can add this name to datatokens.