# Get Obsolete attribute using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, ndepend

Anyone knows how to get the Obsolete attribute when using Linq?

I'm doing NDepend but anyways I want to make a query and get all the obsolete attributes from the methods that are supposed to be "deprecated"

`Obsolete["I WANT THIS STRING"]`

Comment: In LINQ/C# per reflection or CINQ/NDepend?

Comment: CLinq/NDepend. If it's possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a custom attribute from object instance in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329738/how-to-get-a-custom-attribute-from-object-instance-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this is what you are looking for

```
from type in YourAssembly
from p in type.GetProperties()
from m in type.GetMembers()
let propertyAttributes = p.GetCustomAttributes(true)
let methodAttributes = m.GetCustomAttributes(true)
where propertyAttributes.Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(ObsoleteAttribute))
     || methodAttributes.Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(ObsoleteAttribute))
select new type;
```

It queries all types in an assembly and selects those which have properties or methods with the ObsoleteAttribute.