# Get datacontract name attribute value

Tags: c#, wcf

I have set my contract name value

```
    [DataContract(Name = "ObjectTypes", Namespace = ""), KnownType(typeof(BaseFunctions))]
```

How do I get the value of the name attribute at runtime?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain bit more in context. Where you want to do this ? At server side or client side? Why you want to do this ?

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329738/how-to-get-a-custom-attribute-from-object-instance-in-c-sharp

Comment: On server side.  I have some generic functions that need this value.